# Card is overflown while I am using column inside it??How can I use it in order to avoid that error?

Tags: flutter, dart, card

I created a card widget that inside should have both text and bar chart. But if I use a column inside the card it results in me in overflow. But it works for me if I only have a bar chart inside without a column.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 20,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: Color(0xff240046),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Fixed Deposit"),           
              BarChartWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Here is the code I used to build the bar chart widget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarChart(BarChartData(
        axisTitleData: FlAxisTitleData(
          show: true,
          leftTitle: AxisTitle(
            titleText: "Interest Rate",
            showTitle: true,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          bottomTitle: AxisTitle(
            titleText: "Banks",
            showTitle: true,
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          bottomTitles: BarTitles.getBottomTitles(),
          leftTitles: BarTitles.getLeftTitles(),
        ),
        gridData: FlGridData(checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return value % BarData.interval == 0;
        }, getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: Colors.white,
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
          );
        }),
        minY: 0,
        maxY: 10,
        groupsSpace: 5,
        barGroups: BarData.barData.map((data) {
          return BarChartGroupData(x: data.id, barRods: [
            BarChartRodData(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
              ),
              y: data.y,
              width: 20,
              colors: [data.color],
            ),
          ]);
        }).toList()));
  }
```

Comment: can you try using mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.min for column which contains barchart?

Comment: @user6327816 I tried it but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Your Padding Widget inside SingleChildSrcollView try below code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
  child: Card(
    shadowColor: Colors.red,
    elevation: 20,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
    color: Color(0xff240046),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Fixed Deposit"),           
          BarChartWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as the first answer above or simple use the `Expanded` widget instead of the `Column`. This issue happens because the `Card` by default **does not** constraint its children

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 20,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: Color(0xff240046),
        child: 
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: **Expanded**(
               child:
                  Column(
                  children: [
                       Text("Fixed Deposit"),           
                       BarChartWidget(),
                   ],
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your column widget with **SingleChildScrollView**.
So wrapping your column with SingleChildScrollView will give the scroll to column children's.

```
return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Card(
        shadowColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 20,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: Color(0xff240046),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Fixed Deposit"),           
                BarChartWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderBarChart#ac60d relayoutBoundary=up24
NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  creator: BarChartLeaf ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ←
    BarChart ← BarChartWidget ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e4886] ←
    Semantics ← Listener ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1256.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(1256.0, Infinity)
This RenderObject has no descendants.

Comment: card widget extended to infinity size, The children are not displaying

Comment: can you please share your barChartWidget() code in your question?

Comment: I added the change bro